# $each response and put it in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want done loop for `response` (three times loop), and i want append they in a `.list` but it don't work for me, (`response` have value in alert). what do i do?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'url',
    data: val,
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {    
        var $unitses = $('<div class="list"></div>');

        $.each(response, function (index, value){
            $('.list', $unitses).append('value.name');
//alert(response);
        });
        $('#rname').append($unitses); // This don't work append
    },
    "error": function (x, y, z) {
        alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
    }
});
```

Comment: How does the `response` object look like?

Comment: `$('.list', $unitses)` will search for an element with class `list` **inside** `$unitses`, but this element does not contain any other elements. You want `$unitses.append(value.name);` instead (note, no quotes) (assuming the response is correct).

Comment: @Felix Kling - yes response is correct, I do not understand how to use it?

Comment: Then that's probably the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.list', $unitses)` will search for an element with class `list` **inside** `$unitses`, but this element does not contain any other elements.

You want `$unitses.append(value.name);` instead (note, no quotes).

This will put all `value.name` values inside that element, one after each other, which is probably not really readable. If you provide an example for `response` and what you expect as output, we can provide better help.